# Is there a way to run 2 instances of karate with Different arguments?

Tags: maven, junit, automated-tests, karate

I want to run karate from two terminals in the same working directory i.e parallelly, so that they may generate different reports but all I am getting are the reports of the latter run even though they run successfully both at the same time. Is there a way to do custom reporting so that I can save all run reports.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are on the latest version (at least Karate 1.0) and you can over-ride the report-directory.

If you are referring to the [standalone JAR](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#output-directory), you use the `-o` or `--output` option.

If you are using the [`Runner` API](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#improved-test-suite-builder) or from within a JUnit test, use the `reportDir()` method.

If none of the above options work, kindly consider this not supported and please contribute code :)